# What should I fill in for not so urgent field in db?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a db schema which requires linkedin url of the people signing up. I dont want them to fill the linkedin id on signup itself, they are free to add it at dashboard. Below given is the code for the model

```
const master = mongoose.model('master', new mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: {type: String, required: true, unique: false},
  lastName: {type: String, required: true, unique: false},
  email:  {type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  linkedinUrl:  {type: String, required: false, unique: false },
  password: {type: String, required: true, unique: false}
},{strict: true}))
```

When I leave the field empty more than once, the db returns me an error

```
error: "{"driver":true,"name":"MongoError","index":0,"code":11000,"errmsg":"E11000 duplicate key error collection: maindb.mentors index: linkedinUrl_1 dup key: { : \"\" }"}"
```

I realise that having multiple null value is an issue. What other value can I use to mask the empty field? Thank you

Comment: You've actually once had code which declared that field as `unique` in your schema. Unfortunately when you did that a **unique** index was created. Changing the schema does not remove that index. What you need to do is drop all indexes on the collection, from either the `mongo` shell or Compass tool. When your application restarts, the mongoose API will create all indexes defined in your schema. But it **never** removes them. You do that **manually**.

Comment: As to the *general question*. You don't want to mark things as `required` or even `unique` unless you are **certain** that ALL code will fill those fields completely on insertion of a new object. And you have indeed gone somewhat *"wild"* with usage of `unique`. That property really should only be set on the **single** or possibly **few** things that determine the **document** to be unique. Since it's tied to index creation, that's basically the only purpose.

Comment: yes, you are right. I had it unique at first. I checked compass and it was still unique. I dropped the whole collection since its new and created another. Now it works fine. thanks.

Comment: If i want to ensure that such a field is not compulsary to be filled but must be unique when done, what other method should i go for? Go through whole db to ensure its unique or is there any other short method?

Comment: please move your answer from comments so that i can mark it